# Get response for check_ajax_referer in WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to show the notice to the user if the nonce check fails using `check_ajax_referer`. However, the function dies itself if fails. So I just wonder that if I die using `wp_die()` manually will that cause any issue or okay to use?

## Die itself

```
if(!check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce')) {
    // the response never sends as the function never reaches here
    wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));
}
```

## Manually Die

```
if(!check_ajax_referer('gs_nonce', 'nonce', FALSE)) {
    wp_send_json_error(__('Do not be nasty with validation', 'group-shop'));
    wp_die();
}
```

## Console

```
{
    success: false,
    data: "Do not be nasty with validation"
}
data: "Do not be nasty with validation"
success: false__proto__: Objectconstructor ...
```

Comment: Can you echo a response?

Comment: Please have a look modified question content. I have added a response.

Comment: Where is your JS?  That is where you'll show the message.  Seems like your Ajax is fine if you're getting a proper response.  Now you just have to use the response in your JS to show it on the frontend.